# ¿Se puede encontrar el numero de likes de una publicación compartida, por cada persona que lo compartió?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Buenas noches con todos, tengo una pregunta con referencia a la api de facebook. Digamos que tengo una web de ventas. y muchos clientes comparten un producto especifico. ¿Es posible saber el numero de likes  que tiene dicha publicación compartida por cada clientes ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí.

A partir de esta [fantástica respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5700882/1468942) veo que puedes hacer:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/?id=http://www.MY-LINK.com&fields=og_object{engagement}&access_token=<access_token>
```

Modificando la versión, tu web, el objeto que quieras analizar y el access token generado para obtener lo que necesitas. Esta consulta te devuelve un objeto `JSON`:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "engagement": {
      "count": 93, 
      "social_sentence": "93 people like this."
    }, 
    "id": "801998203216179"
  }, 
  "id": "http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/06/they-should-have-announced-at-420/"
}
```

Comment: mmm.. haber  pero eso me devuelve el numero de likes de mi publicación. pero haber. Te explico mi idea principal. Yo quisiera que los usuarios puedan compartir mi publicación. digamos que un usuario x compartió y le dieron 5 personas like a lo que compartió, luego otra persona comparte mi publicación y a esa publicación que compartió le dieron 10 likes. Me gustaría saber el conteo de esos likes, y claro a la persona que pertenece.